# Glassfish unable to deploy at root because default-web-module is declared

Tags: java, deployment, glassfish

While trying to deploy to Glassfish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 (build 5) from both `Netbeans` and `Admin Console` the following message is thrown. Eventhough the `Applications` section of the `Admin Console` has no deployed applications. I have tried restarting the domain without success.

`Exception while loading the app : java.lang.Exception: WEB0145: Unable to deploy web module [*module name*] at root context of virtual server [server], because this virtual server declares a default-web-module`

Is there any cache or something that can be emptied in order to clean up the root so I can once again deploy my application at root context? Thanks for any help!

**Step 1**

I started with a simple `grep`-command on my `Glassfish`-directory for `"default-web-module"`. Seems this was defined in `domains/domain1/config/domain.xml` (how could I have missed to think of that?).

**Step 2**

Inside `domain.xml` is the following:

```
<applications>
    <application context-root="/" ...>
         ...
    </application>
    ...
</applications>
```

Also, this `application` caries multiple references to the applicationname that was previously deployed in `root-context="/"`. As soon as I'm home I will try removing this `<application context-root="/" ...>...</application>` (ofcourse with a backup of `domain.xml`). Hope this will solve the problem and that I will be able to deploy to `root` again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I ran into the problem it's probable that others will too. For this reason I will answer my own question instead of deleting it.

Following the steps I've mentioned in the question, I noticed the config in `domain.xml` still had reference to an application with `context-root="/"`. Upon removing this application from the file and saving it, I could once again deploy an application to `/`!

Answer (score 2):

There 2 ways:

1. From Glassfish admin.

   `Configurations -> server-config -> Virtual Servers -> server`. Then select empty row for `Default Web Module` attribute and save.
2. Open file `glassfish/domains/{your_domain_name}/config/domain.xml`, find line similar to

```xml
<virtual-server id="server" default-web-module="web-module-name.war" network-listeners="http-listener-1,http-listener-2"></virtual-server>
```

and delete `default-web-module` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set other default web module with

```
asadmin set server.http-service.virtual-server.server.default-web-module=<name of the module>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the fact that glassfish assigns any newly deployed web module to all the available virtual servers except the _asadmin one. If any one of the servers already has a default web module assigned to it you will get this error. The solution is to login into your glassfish web admin navigate to `configurations > server-config > Virtual Servers` click on each of your virtual servers and remove the assigned default web modules. Deploy your application and then reassign each web module to its respective virtual server.