# How to hide context root

Tags: apache, glassfish-3

I've configured Glassfish 3.1 + Apache 2 with jk_mod.
All is well when I type in `http://myserver.com/myapp`, it does displays the index page.

I need help to change from `http://myserver.com/myapp` to `http://myserver.com` and it should still go to `myapp`. 
Please let me know if this is *even* possible.?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

You can set a **Default Web Module** for the default **Virtual Server** named `server`.

To do this, deploy your application, open the GlassFish Admin GUI, go to `server-config` -> `Virtual Servers` -> `server` and look for the setting **Default Web Module**. Select your web application and save. Now you can reach your web application on `http://myserver.com`. Be aware that your Apache configuration has to be in sync with the new context root.

You can also set it up via `asadmin`:

```
set server-config.http-service.virtual-server.server.default-web-module=<YOUR_WEBAPP>
```

**See also:**

- [Oracle GlassFish Server 3.1 Administration Guide - Administering Virtual Servers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/ggncs.html)
- [Glassfish unable to deploy at root because default-web-module is declared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16406786/glassfish-unable-to-deploy-at-root-because-default-web-module-is-declared)

Comment: Thanks. I tried it. It went to my index page but now my faces components are not getting loaded. All I'm getting a page without any styles applied. Anything I may be missing?

Comment: I guess this has to do with your mapping to the FacesServlet in your `web.xml`. If you use xhtml files you can change your mapping to `*.xhtml`.

Comment: Mapping seems to be fine in my `web.xml`. I'm thinking of doing it the `filter` way. Any thoughts?

Comment: Not really. Maybe you can add your `web.xml` to the question.