# Changing context path or URL to exclude project name

Tags: netbeans, glassfish

Simple question.

Using Netbeans 8.0 and Glassfish 4, How do I remove the project name from the URL.
For example:

From

http:// localhost/webproject.war/homepage.html

To

http:// localhost/homepage.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a **Default Web Module** for the default **Virtual Server** named `server`.

To do this, deploy your application, open the GlassFish Admin GUI, go to `server-config` -> `Virtual Servers` -> `server` and look for the setting **Default Web Module**. Select your web application and save. Now you can reach your web application on `http://myserver.com`.

Be aware, that if you have something like Apache in front of your GlassFish server, you have to keep the mapping in sync with that.

You can also set it up via `asadmin`:

```
set server-config.http-service.virtual-server.server.default-web-module=<YOUR_WEBAPP>
```

**See also:**

- [Oracle GlassFish Server 3.1 Administration Guide - Administering Virtual Servers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/ggncs.html)
- [Glassfish unable to deploy at root because default-web-module is declared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16406786/glassfish-unable-to-deploy-at-root-because-default-web-module-is-declared)

Comment: Ihr Seid den Mann!! Deutschland wird die Weltmeisterschaft gewinnen lol.  It works now... www.webbubble.org.uk a full fletched enterprise application.  Glassfish is good to learn  but Tomcat is probably better.  I did not find any articles on configuring glassfish.  Do you know any good sites.  How would you compare Glassfish to Catalina Tomcat EE?

Comment: I hope we will win. I don't have any experience with TomEE but I guess that GlassFish is probably more complete because it is the reference implementation, but therefore TomEE is more lightweight (means it consumes less resources). The GlassFish Oracle docs contain a lot of information about configuring the server, otherwise Google is your friend :)