# Handling unexpected shutdown of server running Payara 5 that declares a default web module

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, payara

I'm having an issue with a Payara 5 instance running on a production server that reboots weekly to perform particular tasks; Windows updates etc. I believe the Payara service is being killed suddenly and Payara is not shutting down gracefully. Upon the service restarting, all applications except for one redeploy correctly. The application that is causing issues is one that is deployed to the context root and is also declared as the default web module.

```
java.lang.Exception: Unable to deploy web module XXXXXXX at root context of virtual server server, because this virtual server declares a default-web-module
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1833)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1745)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:123)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:294)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:357)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.initialize(ApplicationLifecycle.java:538)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.postConstruct(ApplicationLoaderService.java:334)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:327)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:375)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:89)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2126)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:116)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1237)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1168)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

My question is, how can I gracefully handle the server restarting and redeploying an application that is "already" deployed at the context root?

Comment: This old SO post for a similar issue with GlassFish may be relevant: [Glassfish unable to deploy at root because default-web-module is declared](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16406786/2985643)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately, I do need this module to be deployed as the default web module and so I cannot fix it using the resolutions in the link.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created service?

`asadmin create-service`

And, in general, you do not need to redeploy your applications. If you do, put artefacts to autodeploy directory of your domain.

Comment: Yes. Payara is running as a service and when it starts it is redeploying the applications and one is failing during this process due to the issue that I mentioned above.